# How to argue that $f$ is convex if $f^\prime$ is increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Consider an open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a $C^{1}$ function $f: I \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f^\prime$ is increasing. The outline of the exercise is given as follows:
>
> - Let $a \in I$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$. Show that $g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
>   $$g(r) = \theta f(a) + (1-\theta)f(r)-f(\theta a + (1-\theta)r)$$
>   has a minimum at $a$.
> - Conclude that $f$ is convex.

I have computed the derivate of $g$:

$$g^\prime(x) = (1-\theta)(f^{\prime}(r)-f^\prime(\theta a+(1-\theta)r))$$

and noticed that $g^\prime(a) = 0$. However, I do not see how to argue that $a$ is indeed a minimum, since I can not take the second derivative here. An idea would be to argue that $g^\prime $ changes signs around $0$, but I do not see how to do this. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve  $r > \theta a +(1-\theta)r$ for $r$ and then use the fact $f'$ is increasing.

Then do the same with $r < \theta a +(1-\theta)r$